# biblatex-musuos: edition as superscript in front of year with crossref

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, superscripts

I have a question related to this one: [biblatex-verbose: edition as superscript in front of year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141985/biblatex-verbose-edition-as-superscript-in-front-of-year)

I'm using `biblatex-musuos` and that solution works for it as well, but only for normal entries. Child entries using crossref do not get a superscript. What confuses me is that it works for both parent and child in `biblatex-verbose`. But `musuos` and `verbose` both require the `authortitle` style and I can't tell what `musuos` does differently that might prevent this from working. The incollection-bibliography driver in `musuos` looks essentially the same as the `standard` one and I don't know what else could influence this. What can I do to make it work in `musuos`? (My apologies if I'm missing something super obvious.)

This is the result I get using `musuos`. If you change the style in the MWE to `verbose` it looks like it's supposed to, with superscript before both years.

[image]

MWE (minor changes compared to linked question marked with comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@mvcollection{parent,
    editor = {Editor, Edith},
    title = {Collectiontitle},
    location = {Somewhere},
    date = {2000},
    edition = {2},
    volume = {1},
}
@InCollection{child,
  author   = {Author, Alf},
  title    = {Title},
  crossref = {parent},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=musuos,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\ifnumcomp{#1}={1}{}% Only use for integers >1
      {\textsuperscript{#1}}}
    {#1\isdot\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}}% changed from \addcomma\space
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}% changed from \addcolon\space
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}% changed from \addcomma\space
  \iffieldint{edition}{%
    \printfield{edition}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
    
\newcommand{\editedition}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{edition}%
     \newunit}
    {\iffieldint{edition}{}{%
      \printfield{edition}%
      \newunit}}%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to patch driver #1}}
}
\editedition{book}
\editedition{collection}
\editedition{inbook}
\editedition{incollection}
\editedition{manual}

\begin{document}

\nocite{parent}
\nocite{child}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons not quite clear to me, `biblatex-musuos` does not use the bibmacro `publisher+location+date` in its driver for `@incollection`, it uses `location+date`.

We will have to redefine `location+date` analogous to `publisher+location+date`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=musuos,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\ifnumcomp{#1}={1}{}% Only use for integers >1
      {\textsuperscript{#1}}}
    {#1\isdot\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}}% changed from \addcomma\space
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}% changed from \addcolon\space
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}% changed from \addcomma\space
  \iffieldint{edition}{%
    \printfield{edition}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldint{edition}{%
    \printfield{edition}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
  \newunit}
    
\newcommand{\editedition}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{edition}%
     \newunit}
    {\iffieldint{edition}{}{%
      \printfield{edition}%
      \newunit}}%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to patch driver #1}}
}
\editedition{book}
\editedition{collection}
\editedition{inbook}
\editedition{incollection}
\editedition{manual}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvcollection{parent,
    editor = {Editor, Edith},
    title = {Collectiontitle},
    location = {Somewhere},
    date = {2000},
    edition = {2},
    volume = {1},
}
@InCollection{child,
  author   = {Author, Alf},
  title    = {Title},
  crossref = {parent},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{parent}
\nocite{child}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Author, Alf: Title. In: Collectiontitle. Vol. 1. Ed. by Edith Editor. Somewhere, 2 2000.]

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I didn't think of that. Regarding the use of `location+date`: In some musicological styles, the publisher is omitted in any case, and only location and date are used. But in `musuos` this doesn't seem like an explanation, since `collection` still uses the publisher, but `incollection` does not. So I'm not sure either. Perhaps an inconsistency in the style?

Comment: @MrBubbles Mhh, yeah. The style doesn't rewrite most other drivers, though, so they mostly still use `publisher+location+date` instead of `location+date`. If the `publisher` is not desired, I'd probably have redefined `publisher+location+date` to drop the `publisher`. The current situation is a bit inconsistent in any case. (As can be seen in the example if you add a `publisher`.)